# why there is error when i use the overload

Tags: c++, boost, overloading, boost-asio

i'm using boost::asio, i want to know why there is error when i use different overload;

````
```
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    io_service ios;
    ip::tcp::acceptor acc(ios);
}
```
````

it can run when i use the command"g++ -o server server.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread"

there is another situation:

````
```
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    io_service ios();
    ip::tcp::acceptor acc(ios);
}
```
````

it cant run and there is the errorinfo:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/executor.hpp:338,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:24,
                 from server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/executor.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::asio::execution_context& boost::asio::executor::impl< <template-parameter-1-1>, <template-parameter-1-2> >::context() [with Executor = boost::asio::io_context (*)(); Allocator = std::allocator<void>]’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/executor.hpp:177:22:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/executor.hpp:179:22: error: request for member ‘context’ in ‘((boost::asio::executor::impl<boost::asio::io_context (*)(), std::allocator<void> >*)this)->boost::asio::executor::impl<boost::asio::io_context (*)(), std::allocator<void> >::executor_’, which is of non-class type ‘boost::asio::io_context (*)()’
  179 |     return executor_.context();
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Adding `()` doesn't mean you're using a different overload. It would still be default-constructing (that is, if it did what you expected, see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
io_service ios();
```

This declares a function called `ios` returning `io_service`. This is known as the ["Most Vexing Parse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Either use `{}` instead of `()` (since C++11) or just leave the parentheses.